# Will DKIM signing work with Multitenancy on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, dkim

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview#DKIM) says:

> If the application sends mail on behalf of an address on the custom domain, it signs mail if responding to a request on the custom domain For example, a request on http://example.com/ to send mail on behalf of emma@example.com. If the user browses http://appid.appspot.com/ instead of the custom domain, the application won't sign the mail.

So if I have an Multitenancy enabled application with custom sub domains for each tenant account, and a Google Apps users registered with my app send emails through my app. Will the message be signed in those cases:

1. Joe (through app) sends email browsing to http://tenant.myapp.com/foo/bar,
   using their own email *joe@tenant.com* as s sender?
2. Joe (through app) sends email browsing to http://tenant.myapp.com/foo/bar,
   using an app admin account email *bounce@myapp.com* as a sender
   and reply-to set to *joe@tenant.com*?

If not, is there a way to use DKIM signing for a case other thatn sending through http://myapp.com/foo/bar page email?

PS. I already have DKIM setup in the Google Apps custom domain myapp.com (and in DNS) used by the App Engine application.